# Error while using subscript: Cannot subscript a value of type... with an index of type

Tags: swift

I want to use `subscript` on a one dimension array of custom type `Cellule`.
This array represent a two dimensional and use a custom type named `Position`to encapsulate.

The code below does not compile with following errors on designated lines:

- Could not find member 'someValue'
- Cannot subscript a value of type '[Cellule]' with an index of type 'Position'

As you may notice `Cellule`type is not optional in the array.

And here is the code:

```
///                                                 
///           ◀──────row──────▶                     
///                                                 
///      ▲    ╔═══════════════╗                     
///      │    ║          ┌─┐  ║                     
///      │    ║          │█│──╬─────▶   Cellule     
///   column  ║          └─┘  ║                     
///      │    ║               ║                     
///      │    ║               ║                     
///      │    ║               ║                     
///      ▼    ╚═════ Grille ══╝      ┌ Position ───┐
///                                  │             │
///                                  │• row        │
///                                  │• column     │
///                                  └─────────────┘


/// Encapsulate position information
struct Position {
    var row: Int
    var column: Int
}

/// Data stored in the array
struct Cellule {
    var someValue:Bool
    /// some other values
}

/// Array to store data
struct Grille {

    let width:Int          // Number of columns
    let height:Int         // Number of lines

    private var laGrille:[Cellule]

    mutating func changeSomething (thePosition: Position, value:Bool) {
        laGrille[thePosition].someValue = active
     /// Error: Could not find member 'someValue'

        let cell:Cellule = laGrille[thePosition]
     /// Error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[Cellule]' with an index of type 'Position'   
    }


    subscript(position:Position) -> Cellule {
        get {
            return laGrille[position.row*width + position.column]
        }
        set {
            laGrille[position.row*width + position.column] = newValue
        }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `subscript(position:Position) -> Cellule` method is a method
of `struct Grille`, so you can apply it only to instances of
that type (and not to `laGrille` which has the type `[Cellule]`).

What you probably meant is

```
self[thePosition].someValue = active
// ....
let cell = self[thePosition]
```

where the subscripting methods then access the (private) `laGrille`
property.

Comment: How, thanks, you're right! Thank you very much!
I then have to encapsulate the array containing `Cellule` on a new type and move the `subscript` on it to obtain:
`laGrille[thePosition].someValue = active`